# NetWare to SLES Apache alias

Tags: apache-2.2, novell

I have a NetWare server running Apache that has directory aliases that call out to other NetWare servers. I'm about to migrate one of those NetWare servers to SLES10SP3 with OES2. When I test the Apache config with a new alias calling to a SLES server, I can get a directory listing of files truncated to 8 characters. I cannot download said files, just get a listing of them. I do have long namespace set on the NSS volume of the SLES server, and indeed if I light up Apache2 on there and call the same directory as an alias, it serves up fine.

So, the only thing that DOESN'T work, is calling it through Apache on the NetWare box.

Any ideas, are appreciated.

Tom

Comment: Is the Apache on your NetWare server Apache 1.3 or 2.0 (or 2.2 for that matter)?

Comment: I am running Apache 1.3 on NetWare 6.5SP8, it was transplated a while ago from a NetWare 5 server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you're running Apache 1.3 on your NetWare server. Apache 1.3 and Apache 2 (and 2.2) are linked to different base libraries. Apache 1.3 is linked to CLIB, the library that originated with NetWare 2.x. Apache 2.0 is linked to LIBC, the replacement for CLIB that was introduced around NetWare 5.x. Because of this, when accessing remote servers CLIB-linked applications had to go to very creative lengths to get names that are not in the DOS namespace. LIBC has native methods for accessing the LONG or UNIX namespaces, and don't have these problems.

It comes down to the NCP semantics used by both libraries.

Your problem comes in when trying to access OES-Linux servers. When Novell ported the NCP stack over to non-NetWare platforms, which they did when they ported eDirectory to Windows/Linux/Solaris/AIX, they chose to not bother with the old-school semantics and just use the newer modern ones. Then OES came along and they just extended the NCP stack they already had for eDir. They didn't put the old semantics in.

In order to access resources on OES-linux servers, you'll need to use Apache 2.0 (or 2.2) on your NetWare servers. Apache 1.3 simply can't do it the way you need.

Comment: Awesome. I'm glad you're the one to answer. I read your blog daily!